# Can we slice an audio file(mp3 or any) into segments(parts of smaller size) programmatically in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, audio

I have a sound file which requires to be split into smaller parts. Is there any way i can do it, dividing an audio file into small slices of sound as Music Cutter does.

I also need to check that sliced parts can be played individually.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Vikas Ojha

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the specific format of the file - an mp3 file, no - a wav file, yes.

For an mp3 file you would have to decompress the audio from the file first (you could use an [audioqueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) ), then split the raw audio data how ever you please, then re-encode each slice as mp3. Apple has sample code for [decoding and encoding mp3's.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html)

This is still not going to enable you to accept *any* input file format, for that you would need other external libraries, such as ffmpeg, LAME, etc. you might have to build these yourself and they may have disagreeable licensing restrictions.